# How to fix "toggle" a "classList" using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have a list to add a class, but just items after add by input works with toggle. The items in the code don't work.

I wonder if is something related to "this" property too.

Link to CodePen.

https://codepen.io/kennedyrmenezes/pen/BaQRXMq

```
li.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var finished = this.classList.toggle("done");
    var removeButton = document.createElement("button");
    removeButton.classList.add("deleteButton");

    if (finished) {
        removeButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("remove"));
        removeButton.classList = "deleteButton";
        li.appendChild(removeButton);

        removeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.parentElement.remove();
        });
    } else {
        this.getElementsByClassName("deleteButton")[0].remove();
    }
})
```

Comment: `removeButton.classList = "deleteButton";` is an issue. If you want to add the class to the existing list use `.add()`, if you want `deleteButton` to be the only class assigned to the element use `removeButton.className = "deleteButton";`

Comment: Oh yes, this: "_The items in the code don't work._" is because you hard coded them in the HTML and your entire toggle thing is only applied to those `<li>`s that are dynamically loaded (not already existing in the HTML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code that you have written, you are only attaching the event handlers to the newly created `li` nodes.
To get around it, you can attach the event handers to all existing `li` elements on page load or you can bind the event handlers once using the concept of [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). I find the 2nd approach to be cleaner as  you don't have to worry about adding handlers when after a new `li` element is added to the `DOM`.

I see the following issues in your code.

- Not attaching the click handler to existing `li` elements.
- Not removing the click handler for the `li` or the `button` when they are being removed ( this can cause memory leaks in the app ).

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var $body = document.querySelector('body');

// attach event handlers using event delegation.

function removeButtonHandler() {
   this.parentElement.remove();
}

$body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const $target = e.target;

  // if target is not li, do nothing
  if ($target.tagName !== 'LI') {
    return;
  }

  var finished = $target.classList.toggle("done");
  var removeButton = document.createElement("button");
  
  removeButton.classList.add("deleteButton");

  if (finished) {
    removeButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("remove"));
    removeButton.classList = "deleteButton";
    
    $target.appendChild(removeButton);

    removeButton.addEventListener("click", removeButtonHandler);
    
  } else {
    var $liRemoveButton = $target.querySelector('button');
    
    if($liRemoveButton) {
      // Also remove the handler for the delete button 
      $liRemoveButton.removeEventListener("click", removeButtonHandler);
    
      $target.removeChild($liRemoveButton);
    }
  }
});

function inputLength() {
  return input.value.length;
}


function creatListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);

  input.value = "";
}

function addListAfterClick() {
  if (inputLength() > 0) {
    creatListElement();
  }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
  if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
    creatListElement();
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);
```

```css
li {
  color: black;
}

h1,
p {
  color: black;
}

button {
  color: white;
  background: #1C3144;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: none;
}

input {
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.testingIt {
  text-decoration-line: line-through;
}

.deleteButton {
  background-color: #A31420;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 20px;
  border-style: none;
}

.done {
  text-decoration: line-through #A31420;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Shopping List</h1>
  <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
  <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
  <button id="enter">Enter</button>
  <ul>
    <li>Notebook</li>
    <li>Jello</li>
    <li>Spinach</li>
    <li>Rice</li>
    <li>Birthday cake</li>
    <li>Candles</li>
  </ul>

</body>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. It worked! Although I still don't recognize some things, I could see what happened, I think I spent a few hours on it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

That because you only listen `click` event for only dymanic added `li` element.

You should add event listenner for hard-code elements also. In example below I show a alert when click to `li` item

```
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(liItem => {
  liItem.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert('click');
  });
})
```

https://codepen.io/1412108/pen/OJbgJEW?editors=1010